# Understanding an awk formula that unwraps fasta files

Tags: awk, bioinformatics

I have just found a formula which can be used to unwrap fasta files. Before I give the formula, I need to explain what unwrapping a fasta file is.
In short, the fasta format is like this:

```
>name_of_sequence$
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx$
>name_of_sequence_2$
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx$
>name_of_sequence_3$
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx$
```

This would be a normal fasta file as I only have one line per sequence (xxxxxx...). The dollar sign are line breaks.

Sometimes however, you can find **wrapped** fasta files like this:

```
>name_of_sequence$
xxxxxxxxx$
xxxxxxxxx$
xxxx$
>name_of_sequence_2$
xxxxxxxxx$
xxxxxxxxx$
xxxx$
>name_of_sequence_3$
xxxxxxxxx$
xxxxxxxxx$
xxxx$
```

Here, you still only have three sequences but each of them are broken into three parts. 
Unwrapping a fasta file means to convert the latter format to the former (one line per sequence).

To do this, you need to remove line breaks from the latter file but not all of them. You would need to keep the line break after the name of the sequence (e.g. here: >name_of_sequence$) and that at the end of the sequence (e.g. here: xxxx$).

It appears that this formula does this:

```
cat infasta | awk '/^>/{print s? s"\n"$0:$0;s="";next}{s=s sprintf("%s",$0)}END{if(s)print s}' > outfasta
```

My question is: Could someone explain to me how it works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is your `awk` script:

```
/^>/ {
    print s ? s "\n" $0 : $0;
    s = "";
    next;
}

{
    s = s sprintf("%s", $0);
}

END {
    if (s)
      print s;
}
```

The first block gets triggered only for lines that start with `>`, i.e. fasta header lines.

In the first block, something gets printed.  That something is `s ? s "\n" $0 : $0`. This means "if `s` is non-zero (or unset), use `s` and add a newline to it followed by the whole of the current line, otherwise just use the whole current line".  In this program, `s` will be a partially read sequence belonging to the most recently processed header line, and when the program hits a header line, this `print` statement will output the last sequence (which is now complete), if there was any, followed by the newly found header line on a new line.

The block then sets `s` to an empty string (we haven't read any sequence belonging to this header yet), and we skip to the next input line.

The next block is executed for all lines of input (but not for header lines as these will be skipped due to the `next` in the previous block).  It simply appends the current line to `s`.  `sprintf` is used, but I'm not quite sure why (`s = s $0` would probably work too).

The last block will be executed after having read all lines of input. It will print the sequence belonging to the last header line, if there was any.

Summary:

The `awk` script concatenates all separate sequence lines by saving them in a variable. When a header line is found, it output the sequence read so far together with the new header on a line of its own.  At the end, the sequence belonging to the last header is outputted.

---

Alternative `awk` script that doesn't store sequence in a variable (may be useful if you have very large genomes in your fasta files):

```
/^>/ {
    if (NR == 1) {
        print;  # 1st header line, just print it.
    } else {
        # Print a newline for the prev. sequence, then the header line on its own line.
        printf("\n%s\n", $0);
    }
    next; # Skip to next input line.
}

{
    printf("%s", $0); # Print sequence without newline.
}

END {
    printf("\n"); # Add final newline to output.
}
```

As a "one-liner":

```
awk '/^>/{if(NR==1){print}else{printf("\n%s\n",$0)}next} {printf("%s",$0)} END{printf("\n")}' sequence.fasta
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this clear explanation. Hopefully, I can apply what I have learnt in the future!

Comment: @Agathe It's funny, usually one wants to do the opposite of this, i.e. fold sequences. You will find answers about that here too (I've written at least one, somewhere).

Comment: @Agathe See updated answer for version suitable for genome-sized fasta files.

Comment: True :) There was a software that did not like my wrapped fasta although can't remember which one now... Thanks for your update, that's great!

Answer (score 0):

FWIW provided a "sed" based solution to wrapped fasta files. The underlying flow of the sed method is upon finding the sequence name line, first of all we display that line on a line by itself and then begin accumulating into the pattern space itself the sequence lines & also stripping off the newline as we go. This flow breaks when either we hit the next sequence name line or eof.

```
sed -e '
  /^>/{                  # caught sequence name line
     n                   # print seq name, next line into pattern space
     :loop
        N                # read next line into PS, if not print PS/quit
        /\n>/!s/\n//     # join successive sequences
     /\n/!bloop          # go back for more seq if new seq name not got yet
     P;D                 # print the current seq then delete it, branch to the top with PS having new seq name
  }
' your_fasta_file
```